# Using JavaScript to create a form

Tags: javascript

OK still very new to JS and not 100% sure what I am doing

I would like to use java script to create a new window with an input form in it.

I was able to get a basic window up and working with a single options drop down but am struggling how to get a form working.

```
var i, l, options = [{
   value: 'fName',
   text: 'First Name:'
},
{
   value:'lName',
   text:'Last Name:'
},

{
   value: 'age',
   text: 'Age:'
},
{
   value:'city:',
   text:'City:'
},
{
   value:'state',
   text:'State:'
},

{
   value:'zCode',
   text:'Zip Code:'
}
                    ],

newWindow = window.open("", null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  

newWindow.document.write("<select onchange='window.opener.setValue(this.value);'>");
for(i=0,l=options.length; i<l; i++) {
    newWindow.document.write("<option value='"+options[i].value+"'>");  
    newWindow.document.write(options[i].text);  
    newWindow.document.write("</option>");
}

newWindow.document.write("</select>");
newWindow.document.title = "Info Window";
```

this works fine but I can't seem to figure out how to switch this over to a form construct. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with DOM element objects instead of building raw HTML. A form can be added to the new window like this:

```
// create a form and set properties
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'http://google.com';
form.method = 'post';

// insert into the body of the new window
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(form);

// add text before the input
var p = document.createElement('p');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Enter text:'));

// add a text input
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'test';
input.value = 'this is an input';
form.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes it much cleaner. 2 Quick Questions 1. I am not getting the name before the input box, and 2. how do I add multiple elements I tried just creating addition elements and didn't seem to take.    Thanls

Comment: To add some text before the input, just do the same thing with `document.createElement()`, but create `<p></p>` or label instead. See updated answer. Adding multiple inputs to the form should work fine, if you're still having trouble, what does the code look like?

Comment: OK I Can get the first input Window up but I am thinking I am messing something up in the createElement flags when I do the second